# Как запретить действие при нажатии на кнопку NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, macos

Пробую написать игру пятнашки. По правилам игры с пустой ячейкой могут меняться только рядом стоящие ячейки (по вертикали и горизонтали).

Проблема в том, что при использовании условия включения либо выключения самой кнопки, после запуска игры значительно путает пользователя так как при произведении действий получается, что не ячейки меняются местами, а крест (активных кнопок) двигается по полю.

```
NSInteger point = 0;
NSArray *arrCells = [self->myMatrix cells];
for (int i = 0; i < arrCells.count; i++)
{
    [[self->myMatrix cells] objectAtIndex:i].enabled = false;
    ((NSButtonCell*)[arrCells objectAtIndex:i]).target = self;
    ((NSButtonCell*)[arrCells objectAtIndex:i]).action = @selector(btnClick:);
    if ([((NSButtonCell*)[arrCells objectAtIndex:i]).title isEqualToString:@""] == true)
    {
        point = i;
    }
}
if(point +1 <= 15)
{
    ((NSButtonCell*)[arrCells objectAtIndex:point+1]).enabled = true;
}
if(point - 1 >= 0)
{
    ((NSButtonCell*)[arrCells objectAtIndex:point-1]).enabled = true;
}
if(point - 4 >= 0)
{
    ((NSButtonCell*)[arrCells objectAtIndex:point-4]).enabled = true;
}
if(point + 4 <= 15)
{
    ((NSButtonCell*)[arrCells objectAtIndex:point+4]).enabled = true;
}
```

Вопрос в том - как запретить действие кнопки не меняя ее визуально.

Comment: Что если не запрещать, а просто никак не обрабатывать нажатие на эту кнопку?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - вместо изменения свойства enabled менять свойство target с nil на self и обратно.